# Framework Error : Include of non-modular header inside framework module

Tags: facebook, swift, frameworks, ios9, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using bolts and FBSDK in my app, but using them both as pods instead of manually adding the frameworks. my app runs perfectly fine and compiles.

But when I go to archive the app to prepare for app store, i get 20+ errors of "Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'FBSDKCoreKit' (and other FBSDK parts)".

I've tried so many solutions on other posts/forums but this error just wont go away. Any suggestions would be appreciated.